# What is the lightest custom Android ROM (Android 4.0 or higher)?

Tags: custom-roms, htc-wildfire-s

I need a minimalistic custom Android ROM which has a lot of RAM free for use because the app that I need to use needs a lot of RAM. I want to only use my phone for one thing and only have one application installed on it. I will install the app after I install Android on my phone. The app is using GPS and needs Android 4.0 or higher. The name of the app is Map My Tracks. What is a custom Android ROM that is the lightest of all? 
My phone is HTC Wildfire S.

Answer (score 1):

There is no definite answer for this but here is my point of view -

**The Simple Solution - SlimRom:**
[SlimRoms](https://slimroms.org/#/download) - On-Click away,free, HTC compatible ROM.
With SlimRom you can configure how much of google services you wish to use which have significant effect on device performance.

**The Hard Solution - Create One:**
You can create your custom [Android OS](https://source.android.com/source/requirements.html) and build clean version of it (without any google app like `chrome` or `youtube`).
If you really want to get wild you can delete all unnecessary apps under `platform/packages/apps` (e.g calculator,camera).
If you choose this option bear in mind that HTC specific features won't work.

**More data:**
If you're still not sure and need more data about specific features that you'll need in your app check the [Custom ROM Comparison Database](http://forum.xda-developers.com/android/general/custom-rom-comparison-database-t3031005#post58850951).

Comment: OK, I will try the simple solution first. :-)